# Use Solid Edge Translator in Design Automation Inventor 2023

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We can successfully use **Solid Edge Translator** in local Inventor 2023 add-in, but it is NOT available in Design Automation for Inventor, used engine: `Autodesk.Inventor+2023`

Why?

Local Inventor `ApplicationAddIn`:

> Translator: Solid Edge - {E2548DAF-D56B-4809-82B9-5F670E6D518B}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was left out by accident

We're planning to add it back in an update.

Comment: Hi Adam, do you have planned a date for this update? Also, do you have a date for the release of Inventor 2024 engine in Design Automation?

Comment: It's still being worked on as the main priority at the moment, but no deadline I'm aware of. I guess it's difficult to estimate.